# saving string matches to list of lists

Tags: python, regex, string, list, dictionary

I have a string while looks like this

```
Name: Thompson shipping co.
17VXCS947
Name: Orange juice no pulp, Price: 7, Weight: 2, Aisle:9, Shelf_life: 30,
67 Name: Orange juice pulp, Price: 7, Weight:2, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:30,
Photo is available,
Photo is available,
56GHIO098
Name: Cranberry Juice, Price: 3, Weight: 1, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:45,
Name: Lemonade, Price:1, Weight:1, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:10,
```

There are no new line characters and everything is one big string.

My end goal is to save them to an excel sheet. I am trying to either save these to list of lists of dictionary which looks like

```
[['Name:  Thompson shipping co.'],['Name: Orange juice no pulp', 'Price: 7', 'Weight: 2', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life: 30'],['Name: Orange juice pulp', 'Price: 7', 'Weight:2', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life:30',['.....']]
```

or a dictionary.

My current solution is to use regex to find Name, Price, Weight, Aisle, Shelf_life with

```
re.findall('(?<=,)[^,]*Name:[^,]*(?=,)'),re.findall('(?<=,)[^,]*Price:[^,]*(?=,)'),re.findall('(?<=,)[^,]*Weight:[^,]*(?=,)')....
```

How do I save them to a list of lists or a dict? Thinking out loud, I can count the iterations and save every 5th one to new list but the first Name occurrence is a corner case.

What's the neater way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

str = '''
Name: Thompson shipping co.
17VXCS947
Name: Orange juice no pulp, Price: 7, Weight: 2, Aisle:9, Shelf_life: 30,
67 Name: Orange juice pulp, Price: 7, Weight:2, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:30,
Photo is available,
Photo is available,
56GHIO098
Name: Cranberry Juice, Price: 3, Weight: 1, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:45,
Name: Lemonade, Price:1, Weight:1, Aisle:9, Shelf_life:10,
'''.replace('\n', ' ')

print([re.findall(r'\b\w+:\s*[^,]+', x) for x in re.findall(r'\bName:\s*.+?(?=\s*\bName|$)', str)])
```

Output:

```
[['Name: Thompson shipping co. 17VXCS947'], ['Name: Orange juice no pulp', 'Price: 7', 'Weight: 2', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life: 30'], ['Name: Orange juice pulp', 'Price: 7', 'Weight:2', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life:30'], ['Name: Cranberry Juice', 'Price: 3', 'Weight: 1', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life:45'], ['Name: Lemonade', 'Price:1', 'Weight:1', 'Aisle:9', 'Shelf_life:10']]
```

- The second `findall()` function creates a list of strings which starts with
  `Name:`.
- The first `findall()` function creates a list of `name: value` pairs
  out of the list items created above.

As seen, the string `17VXCS947` is appended to the first list element.
If you want to remove it, we'll need another logic to exclude it.

Comment: wow! Brilliant, that's a very cool approach. This brings a lot of unwanted text as you said, I guess I can clean it.